# Jquery font size animation problem in Chrome, too laggy

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, fonts, jquery-animate, lag

I developed a little script that make texts like they were coming from far, with Jquery and animate() function. Everything works well in IE and FireFox but on Chrome is very laggy, like it was loosing frames.

You cand test and play with the code here:
http://jsbin.com/ehahoc/7/

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I check the source and i something that mite couse the problem...
Form firefox the font size and the opacity values are

0.0000 (4 digits)

and in chrome...

0.000000000000 (12-14 digits)

and the increased like :

0.000000000011

0.000000000124

0.000000000180
......

Don't know if this helps or if this makes it buggy.

Comment: You're right, I've noticed that. I'm not a pro with Jquery, but I don't think I can operate something on this side, I just use a function:
`code`$('.container .active-text').animate({opacity:1, fontSize: "14px"}, 4000);`code`

Comment: Hm..you can ;)
i think there is a way to take the values, covert them to the currect style and set them to the style property of the element.
Don't ask me how..:P
I have the same problem with my site and i create my own implementation of this animation.

Comment: Ok, thank Sanosay. Do you think I could take a look to the animation on your site to be inspired? Does someone else can elaborate this suggestion a little?